# How to decompress a large Grid?

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, grid, facet

I created a super large grid and now I cannot view the image.

Is there a way for me to save it as png or similar and use a magnifying glass to see each facet?

I have tried viewing it in the R itself, saving with ggsave, saving with cairo and exporting.

Here, I show you my script and the image

```
#install.packages("ggh4x")
library(ggh4x)

qPCR_data$Treatment <- factor(qPCR_data$Treatment, levels =c("NW","S","NS","Ec6","Ec7"))
qPCR_data$Wing <- factor(qPCR_data$Wing, levels =c("Wounded","Control"))


qPCR_grid <- ggplot(qPCR_data, aes(x=factor(SampleID), y=CtGene, colour=Replicate,group=Gene)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill=Gene),position=position_dodge(0.3))+
  facet_nested(TimePoint~Wing+Treatment)

ggsave("qPCR_grid2.png", plot=qPCR_grid)

qPCR_grid
```

[image]

Comment: You need to either find a different way to plot your data, or save the file as a huge image. Try `ggsave("qPCR_grid2.png", plot=qPCR_grid, width = 3000, height = 2000, units = "px")`

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to read all the labels on the y axis? Looks too dense to interpret meaningfully.

Comment: The notes on the y axis are valid - seems to be a factor, right? So no way to fix the labeling intelligently unless you have a method in mind (and we need specifics to help).  About the x axis, do you want to pull out individual sampleIDs here?  Why not use `Treatment` as the x axis and apply a jitter in the x direction to your points so that you can see invidual samples?  You lose any continuity of sampleID, but that's probably asking too much of the viewer here to identify info at that level.